# Extra controller came before My jquery call back function

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    var newBuddies = setInterval(function()
{
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    $('#onlinebuddies').load('buddies/index/'+ timestamp);
}, 10000);
```

> Here calling to https://localhost/yellow/chat/index but its calling to https://localhost/yellow/home/chat/index another controller name coming

Comment: http://localhost/yellowbuz/index.php/home/chat/get_new_messages/1487326302341 don't need home controller....

Comment: Try to set your URL with `<?php echo base_url('buddies/index')?>`

Comment: Try change to `$('#onlinebuddies').load('/buddies/index/'+ timestamp);` I guess the page with the JS has the `home` path? You should use an absolute path...

Comment: thnku for your response@jtheman: ya its in the the home controller..how can i specify exact path in the JS.like ajax calling  $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'base_url+"index.php/chat/index"); ?>',
            data:{"timestamp":timestamp},
            success:function(data){
                $("chatmessage").html(data);}
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you call this script from a page inside `http://localhost/yellow/home/` , then it will call `http://localhost/yellow/home/chat/index`. 
To call `http://localhost/yellow/chat/index`, first go up and then go to the path you want.

```
var newBuddies = setInterval(function()
{
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    $('#onlinebuddies').load('../buddies/index/'+ timestamp);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: its worked, but when i click href link ,i need same js on that page also but there again happening same thing, what i need is http://localhost/yellow/chat/get_new_messages but lint is http://localhost/yellow/home/inner/chat/get_new_messages.my jquery function call like  $('#newmessage').load('../chat/get_new_messages/'+ timestamp);
},2000);  .... please  help

Comment: Add ../../ instead of ../  the path ../ represents one level up.